# Installing Shorewall on a virtual server: ERROR: Your kernel/iptables do not include state match support

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, virtuozzo

I just got a virtual server (I think virtuozzo) with root access. I wanted to install shorewall but when I want to start it I get the error message

```
# shorewall start
Compiling...
Processing /etc/shorewall/shorewall.conf...
ERROR: Your kernel/iptables do not include state match support. No version of Shorewall will run on this system
```

So now I'm wondering what can I do? The system ist ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Don't know why this is getting down voted, seems legit!

Comment: @SimonJGreen the OP wants to do things which are beyond their control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking you are on openVZ and they haven't configured the server correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "haven't configured the server correctly"?

Comment: In openVZ you need to configure the host to explicitly allow this like Tom suggested.

Answer (score 8):

Virtuozzo is an interesting type of virtualisation.  It's actually a "jail" - in the FreeBSD sense, rather than a hypervisor type Virtual Machine, like KVM.  As a result, you need to tune the options of the Virtual Machine Host, to allow certain kernel functions to be passed through.

I believe that Virtuozzo is effectively OpenVZ (or similar enough) underneath, so you'll need to edit `/etc/vz/vz.conf` 
and add "`ipt_state`" to the `IPTABLES` variable, then restart the VM. ([source](http://forum.proxmox.com/threads/1936-Shorewall-on-OpenVZ-containers))

Of course, you might not be able to do this, if you don't have control over the VM Host.

Comment: No, I don't have access to the VM host.

Comment: Well, you're SOL then.